# Parsing XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have several large .xml files. I want to parse out the files to do several things.

I want to pull out only:

- XML-/title1 and save it to list A (for example)
- XML-/title2 and save it to list B
- XML-/title3 and save it to list C
- etc, etc

Using Python 2.x which library would be best to import/use. How would I set this up?
Any Suggestions?

For Example:

```
 <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
        <PMID Version="1">8981971</PMID>
        <Article PubModel="Print">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Print">0002-9297</ISSN>
                <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
                    <Volume>60</Volume>
                    <Issue>1</Issue>
                    <PubDate>
                        <Year>1997</Year>
                        <Month>Jan</Month>
                    </PubDate>
                </JournalIssue>
                <Title>American journal of human genetics</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>Am. J. Hum. Genet.</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>mtDNA and Y chromosome-specific polymorphisms in modern Ojibwa: implications about the origin of their gene pool.</ArticleTitle>
            <Pagination>
                <MedlinePgn>241-4</MedlinePgn>
            </Pagination>
            <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Scozzari</LastName>
                    <ForeName>R</ForeName>
                    <Initials>R</Initials>
                </Author>
            </AuthorList>
        <MeshHeadingList>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Alleles</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="Y">Y Chromosome</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
        </MeshHeadingList>
        <OtherID Source="NLM">PMC1712541</OtherID>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
```

Comment: I'd use `xml.dom.minidom` for this, it comes with Python and works fine. `lxml` is another good library but you'd have to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I have found this library very handy. And as just pointed out, BeautifulStoneSoup specifically is for parsing XML.

Comment: Specifically, BeautifulStoneSoup

Comment: Thanks ALL, I choose BeautifulSoup as my route. I found that B.S. documenation was just clearer than that of lxml.

Comment: In the new version's documentation: There is no longer a `BeautifulStoneSoup` class for parsing XML. To parse XML you pass in “xml” as the second argument to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor.

Comment: I haven't read the new documentation. Feel free to edit my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try look at the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module.

To locate the titles you can use [Xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) with lxml, or you can use the xml object structure in lxml to "index" you down to the title elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want each title in its own list, which your question leads me to believe.

How about all the titles in one list?  The following example uses a trimmed version of your sample XML, plus I duplicated an `<Article/>` to show that using `lxml.etree.xpath` creates the list of `<Title/>'s` for you:

```
>>> import lxml.etree

>>> xml_text = """<PubmedArticle>
  <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
    <PMID Version="1">8981971</PMID>
    <Article PubModel="Print">
      <Journal>
        <ISSN IssnType="Print">0002-9297</ISSN>
        <!-- <JournalIssue ... /> -->
        <Title>American journal of human genetics</Title>
        <ISOAbbreviation>Am. J. Hum. Genet.</ISOAbbreviation>
      </Journal>
      <ArticleTitle>mtDNA and Y chromosome-specific polymorphisms in modern Ojibwa: implications about the origin of their gene pool.</ArticleTitle>
      <!--<Pagination>
          ...
          </MeshHeadingList>-->
      <OtherID Source="NLM">PMC1712541</OtherID>
    </Article>
    <Article PubModel="Print">
      <Journal>
        <ISSN IssnType="Print">9297-0002</ISSN>
        <!-- <JournalIssue ... /> -->
        <Title>American Journal of Pediatrics</Title>
        <ISOAbbreviation>Am. J. Ped.</ISOAbbreviation>
      </Journal>
      <ArticleTitle>Healthy Foo, Healthy Bar</ArticleTitle>
      <!--<Pagination>
          ...
          </MeshHeadingList>-->
      <OtherID Source="NLM">PMC1712541</OtherID>
    </Article>
  </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>"""
```

XPaths are made to return nodes which `lxml.etree.xpath` translates into a Python list of node objects:

```
>>> xml_obj = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml_text)
>>> for title_obj in xml_obj.xpath('//Article/Journal/Title'):
        print title_obj.text 

American journal of human genetics
American Journal of Pediatrics
```

**EDIT 1: Now with Python's xml.etree.ElementTree**

I wanted to show this solution with the included module in case installing a third party module is not possible or unattractive.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
>>> element = ETree.fromstring(xml_text)
>>> xml_obj = ETree.ElementTree(element)
>>> for title_obj in xml_obj.findall('.//Article/Journal/Title'):
    print title_obj.text


American journal of human genetics
American Journal of Pediatrics
```

It's small, but this XPath is *not* identical to the XPath in the `lxml` example: there is a  period ('.') at the beginning.  Without the period, I got this warning (with Python 2.7.2):

```
>>> xml_obj.findall('//Article/Journal/Title')

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
FutureWarning: This search is broken in 1.3 and earlier, and will be fixed in a future version.  If you rely on the current behaviour, change it to './/Article/Journal/Title'
```

Comment: I finally got around to looking at all the answers posted. Thanks for the effort! I was able to install the lxml library no problem but I had a hellava time going thru the documentation.  I just couldn't wrap my head around, at the time.  I found BeautifulSoup's docs little easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Try [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with [xpath expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

A short snippet

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml = """<foo><bar/>baz!</foo>"""
>>> doc = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> doc.xpath('//foo/text()') #xpath expr
['baz!']
>>>
```

if you have a `xml file` than

```
s = StringIO(xml)
doc = etree.parse(s)
```

You can use `Firebug addon` to fetch the `xpath expr`.

Answer (score -1):

ElementTree is awesome and comes with Python.